# Spark Kafka 0.10 NoSuchMethodError org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.assign

Tags: apache-spark

I am running into a NoSuchMethodError when I try to use Kafka integration for Structured Streaming. The stack trace looks like this when there is the very first record available:
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.assign(Ljava/util/Collection;)V
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.createConsumer(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.<init>(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer$.getOrCreate(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDD$$anon$1.<init>(KafkaSourceRDD.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDD.compute(KafkaSourceRDD.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
...
```

My sbt has these dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    scalaTest % Test,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.1.0" % "provided",
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.6.0" % "provided"
)
```

and Scala version is 2.11.8.

I am able to run spark applications for dataframe. It's only the Kafka integration giving me this error. The structured streaming code is just the example from documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html):

```
  val ds1 = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "data01:9092,data02:9092,data03:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "cluster-topic-01")
  .load()
  val ds2 = ds1.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  val query = ds2.writeStream
        .format("console")
        .start()
  query.awaitTermination()
```

Any advice where I can look at the problem? 
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you have a stray Kafka client somewhere in the runtime classpath that is being loaded instead of the one `spark-sql-kafka-0-10` has a dependency on.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the error is from a Cloudera yarn cluster and it has a Flume installed as below:

/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/kafka-clients-0.9.0-kafka-2.0.2.jar
/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/kafka_2.10-0.9.0-kafka-2.0.2.jar

Spark 2.1.0 has this line in conf/spark-env.sh 
SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="$SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/*"
which is the root cause.

I have a Hadoop client machine which doesn't have Flume installed and it works flawlessly. Now commenting out the line in spark-env.sh let me run my structured streaming on yarn as well.

Comment: Yup, it is always something like that with these `Error`s in Spark like `NoSuchMethodError` and `NoClassDefFoundError`. Glad you found the problem. Good luck on your project! An upvote would be appreciated.

Comment: So it seems my machine has `kafka-clients 0.8` on classpath. How do I override that to use 0.10 (since I have `spark-sql-kafka-0-10` as a dependency, which depends on `kafka-clients-0.10.0.1`)? I tried adding `dependencyOverrides += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.0.1"` to my `build.sbt`, still getting the same error

Comment: @lfk, did you get the way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

In modern CDH distributions (e.g. Cloudera 5.12) there is a simpler way.

1. In Cloudera Manager's UI go to Spark2 tab and then to "configuration".
2. Search the necessary config by "kafka" keyword. You should find `spark_kafka_version` config set to '0.9' or 'None'.
3. Set "0.10" value and deploy client configuration.
4. Reboot Spark2 service if necessary.

If the above way doesn't work (no '0.10' value or no such configuration in Cloudera), you can edit the config manually:

1. Open the file `/etc/spark2/conf.cloudera.spark2_on_yarn/spark-env.sh` in any editor.
2. Edit 2 configs (`SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION` and `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH`) in such way:
   `SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION=${SPARK_KAFKA_VERSION:-'0.10'}`
   `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="$SPARK_HOME/kafka-0.10/*"`
3. Do steps 1-2 on each YARN node and on the client node.