# Spark streaming and kafka Missing required configuration "partition.assignment.strategy" which has no default value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to run the spark streaming application with Kafka using yarn. I am getting the following Stack trace error-

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "partition.assignment.strategy" which has no default value.
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:124)
>       at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.(AbstractConfig.java:48)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig.(ConsumerConfig.java:194)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:380)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:363)
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:350)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer.(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:45)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.CachedKafkaConsumer$.get(CachedKafkaConsumer.scala:194)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDDIterator.(KafkaRDD.scala:252)
>       at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaRDD.compute(KafkaRDD.scala:212)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)

Here is snippet of my code of how I am creating my KafkaStream with spark stream-

```
        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(60))

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "*boorstrap_url:port*",
  "security.protocol" -> "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
  "sasl.kerberos.service.name" -> "kafka",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "annotation-test",
  //Tried commenting and uncommenting this property      
  //"partition.assignment.strategy"->"org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean))

val topics = Array("*topic-name*")

val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))
val valueKafka = kafkaStream.map(record => record.value())
```

I have gone through the following post -

1. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4547
2. [Pyspark Structured Streaming Kafka configuration error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959483/pyspark-structured-streaming-kafka-configuration-error?rq=1)

According to this I have updated my kafka util jar in my fat jar to **0.10.2.0** version from **0.10.1.0** packaged by default from spark-stream-kafka-jar as transient dependency. Also my job is working fine when I am running it on single node by setting master as local. I am running spark 2.3.1 version.

Comment: can you try changing your strategy to "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor" or instead of "partition.assignment.strategy" try setting "consumer.partition.assignment.strategy"

Comment: I tried it then I am getting the error-

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.assign(Ljava/util/Collection;)V

Comment: try setting "consumer.partition.assignment.strategy" instead of ""partition.assignment.strategy".

Comment: I am getting the same error- Missing required configuration "partition.assignment.strategy" which has no default value.

Comment: I think that question might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035542/spark-kafka-0-10-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-kafka-clients-consumer-kafkaconsum

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I do not have any other kafka client in my environment. I am also submitting the spark job with  --conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true --conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true to check for class in my fat jar first.

Answer (score 0):

Add `kafka-clients-*.jar` to your spark jar folder. `kafka-clients-*.jar` is in `kafka-*/lib` directory.